# Listen on data using Wt framework

Tags: c++, json, server, frameworks, wt

It's easy to create a webpage with Wt on whatever port for example 200.59.43.32:3333.

However, is there a function (which I can't find) to listen on the same port when someone sends data to it (some string of data, json etc). In other words, if someone send a string "much data" data to 200.59.43.32:3333, how can I capture it using Wt?

Edit: If it's not possible with a plain string, is it possible with a proper JSON?

I'm aware I could open another port to listen on such a string using (linux) socket/bind etc..

Answer (score 1):

If it's just random data, there is no way that I know that you can do it with Wt. In that case, you could use a reverse proxy solution like HAProxy and forward any HTTP traffic to Wt, and any other traffic to another socket.

If you're talking about HTTP traffic, static resources may be what you are after. Wt's implementation of the [TechEmpower framework benchmarks](https://github.com/emweb/wt/blob/master/examples/te-benchmark/benchmark.cpp) contains some custom static resources that you could base your code on. For example, there's the `PlaintextResource`:

```
class PlaintextResource : public Wt::WResource {
  virtual void handleRequest(const Wt::Http::Request &request, Wt::Http::Response &response) {
    response.setMimeType("text/plain");
    response.addHeader("Server", "Wt");

    response.out() << "Hello, World!";
  }
};
```

You can use the `request` variable to retrieve any data about the request, see [Wt::Http::Request](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1Http_1_1Request.html).

You can make this resource accessible like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  try {
    Wt::WServer server(argv[0]);

    server.setServerConfiguration(argc, argv, WTHTTP_CONFIGURATION);

    PlaintextResource plaintextResource;
    server.addResource(&plaintextResource, "/plaintext");

    if (server.start()) {
      int sig = Wt::WServer::waitForShutdown(argv[0]);

      std::cerr << "Shutdown (signal = " << sig << ")" << std::endl;
      server.stop();
    }
  } catch (Wt::WServer::Exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    return 1;
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what if the string is a proper JSON though?

Comment: If you are sending JSON over HTTP, then you can retrieve the JSON from `request.in()`, which returns an `std::istream&`.

You could then parse it with `Wt::Json::parse()`, see https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/namespaceWt_1_1Json.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send plain strings, you need to open a socket. HTTP applications talk to clients using HTTP protocol, so to do this "Wt-way", you should do a HTTP request, GET or POST.

From what I understand, you need to create a `WResource` and register it within server using `WServer::addResource()` to give it a fixed URL. After that reimplement `WResource::handleRequest()` to access HTTP request data.